# Sharepoint 2013: add a field to Discussion Threaded view

Tags: 2013

We have an apparently easy requirement but we were not able to find the solutions.. how can we add a field to the Threaded view of a discussion? We cannot do any server side modifications, we can use only Sharepoint Designer, JSlink on web parts, etc.

To provide more detail, we have a discussion used for the approval process of a document. The doc creator generates a new entry in the discussion for the review. The reviewers post comments, and the doc creator will correct and post corrected version of the doc. At the end, the reviewers approve the doc. The doc itself is not loaded in the discussion, but there is a field "Document Link" with the link to the doc in a shared folder. We need to include the "Document Link" field in the Threaded view, so any person opening the thread can see the links and open the different versions of the doc.

We are not able to use other views for this, as the Threaded view is the only one having the information for the initial post and the replies in a single view (Flat view also have it, but the "Reply" link only shows the "Body" field, so other custom fields like Document Link" cannot be added)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for our requirement without modifying the Threaded view, I post it here in case somebody finds it useful:

1. Remove the read-only tag for Flat view. For this, edit the Flat view
   in Sharepoint Designer, then change the parameter ReadOnly="TRUE" to
   "FALSE" within the View tag
2. Create a new view based on Flat view    (this can be done only if the
   Flat view is not readonly)
3. Change the view    to Basic Table style

This view will contain the original post as well as all the replies, and any custom field can be added to it